# Deprecation Errors - How to Fix?

Tags: craft3, error-message, deprecation

We are in development of our new site in Craft 3 and we are getting some deprecation errors. This is keeping us from using Craft Commerce for our ordering page. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

```
Message Origin  Last Occurrence Stack Trace 
The Purchasable::getPurchasableId() function has been deprecated. Use Purchasable::getId() instead. /srv/captioncall/templates/buy/index.twig:6 Yesterday   Stack Trace 
craft.session.getFlash() has been deprecated. Use craft.app.session.getFlash() instead. /srv/captioncall/templates/buy/index.twig:33    Yesterday   Stack Trace 
craft.session.getFlash() has been deprecated. Use craft.app.session.getFlash() instead. /srv/captioncall/templates/buy/index.twig:34    Yesterday   Stack Trace
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I can tell you much more than the error messages are telling you, you need to update your twig code eg. in index.twig (line 6) where it says; `getPurchasableId()` change it to `getId()`.

These errors are just warning you that a future version of Craft won't support them (I imagine it will be Craft 4, but could be sooner).

Changing e-commerce systems based on this error would not be advised as it's a very simple fix!

Comment: Thank you so much. I am new to Craft and Twig and we have a third party helping us get all this setup in a staging environment before we deploy to our primary server. So, it's not alarming. I really appreciate you getting back to me so fast.

Comment: @SamSumpter can you mark this question as answered?